# 2 tables won't go under each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a website using bootstrap, but have ran into a problem. In the included screenshot you can see I have 2 tables under each other, but I went those 2 tables to be next to each other. I have tried all kinds of variations, but none of them seem to work.

Here is my current code;

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h5>DIEREN</h5>
    <hr>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw dier toevoegen</a>
      <table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
          <th>Soort</th>
          <th>Naam</th>
          <th>Wijzigen</th>
          <th>Verwijderen</th>
          <th>Gegevens</th>
        </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h5>BEZOEKEN</h5>
    <hr>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw bezoek inplannen</a>
      <table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
          <th>Dier</th>
          <th>Brengen</th>
          <th>Halen</th>
          <th>Wijzigen</th>
          <th>Verwijderen</th>
          <th>Bevestiging</th>
        </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the columns in a `<div class="row">` object. Make sure you're familiar with the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). This code works:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h5>DIEREN</h5> 
            <hr>
            <div class="card card-body">
                <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw dier toevoegen</a>
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Soort</th>
                        <th>Naam</th>
                        <th>Wijzigen</th>
                        <th>Verwijderen</th>
                        <th>Gegevens</th>
                    </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h5>BEZOEKEN</h5>
            <hr>
            <div class="card card-body">
                <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw bezoek inplannen</a>
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dier</th>
                        <th>Brengen</th>
                        <th>Halen</th>
                        <th>Wijzigen</th>
                        <th>Verwijderen</th>
                        <th>Bevestiging</th>
                    </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am still learning Bootstrap, but the grid system is making more and more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap two columns with a `<div>` with class `row`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h5>DIEREN</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw dier toevoegen</a>
        <table class="table table-sm">
          <tr>
            <th>Soort</th>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Wijzigen</th>
            <th>Verwijderen</th>
            <th>Gegevens</th>
          </tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>
        </table>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h5>BEZOEKEN</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw bezoek inplannen</a>
        <table class="table table-sm">
          <tr>
            <th>Dier</th>
            <th>Brengen</th>
            <th>Halen</th>
            <th>Wijzigen</th>
            <th>Verwijderen</th>
            <th>Bevestiging</th>
          </tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you need to wrap your columns inside a div with a class of row for them to be on same row.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h5>DIEREN</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw dier toevoegen</a>
        <table class="table table-sm">
          <tr>
            <th>Soort</th>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Wijzigen</th>
            <th>Verwijderen</th>
            <th>Gegevens</th>
          </tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>
        </table>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h5>BEZOEKEN</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Nieuw bezoek inplannen</a>
        <table class="table table-sm">
          <tr>
            <th>Dier</th>
            <th>Brengen</th>
            <th>Halen</th>
            <th>Wijzigen</th>
            <th>Verwijderen</th>
            <th>Bevestiging</th>
          </tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Wijzigen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Verwijderen</a></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block" href="">Print</a></td>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
display:inline-block
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure but have you tried to use the row class?

```html
<div class="row">
<!-- Your tables code here -->
</div>
```